# How can I change encoded data in the beforeSend function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to write an ajax script to get a response session_key during the first request, and then loop the script for another X times using the same session_key in order to retrieve more results, however I'm not being able to change the payload data with the session_key

The script and loop is working fine however I'm starting a new session each loop as I'm not being able to send the same session_key on the payload

Tried to keep the session_key inside an input and using beforeSend to change the payload, however it doesn't work as well

```
var all_results = [];

encodedata = JSON.stringify({"q": "Italy","session_key":""});

$.ajax({
    url: document.location.origin + '/api/search',
    type : 'POST',
    data : encodedata,
    tryCount : 0,
    retryLimit : 4,
    contentType:'application/json',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {              

        // get the session_key and update the payload
        this.data.session_key = $("#session_key").val();

    },
    success :  function(data) {

       var result = $.parseJSON(data);
       all_results = all_results.concat(result);

       // get the session_key from the first result and keep inside an input
       $("#session_key").val(result.session_key);

        this.tryCount++;
        if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
            $.ajax(this);
            return;                                
        } else {
           // code to use the result...
        }

    }
});
```

Loop the ajax request using the same session_key (retrieved during the first loop)

Comment: You're changing the session_key on the page, not the value in the `encodedata` variable...  It needs to change the value in the `this.data` string to have the new session_key

Comment: `this.data.session_key = $("#session_key").val();` should be resulting in an error as you are setting the `data` as a string, not an object.  So the `.session_key` should be returning undefined.  You need to parse it, change it, and stringify it again.

Comment: @Taplar should I parse+change+stringfy the encodedata inside beforeSend?

Comment: I might suggest removing the stringify of encodedata and leave it the object.  Then the beforeSend can simply update it, and stringify it when setting data.

Comment: @Taplar thanks! It worked doing this way